# Remove template segment from URL

Tags: url

Is it possible to remove the template group from the url so instead of http://example.com/blog/article/postone it would be http://example.com/blog/postone. I already stripped the index.php via .htaccess.

My blog/index code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="8" orderby="date" sort="desc"}
  <h1>{title}</h1>
  <p>{blog_except}</p>
  <p><a href="{title_permalink='blog/article'}">{title}</a></p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And my blog/article code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="1"}
  <h1>{title}</h1>
  <p>{blog_body}</p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just simple routing so I'd look to use [Freeway](https://github.com/averyvery/freeway) here. Then you can just map up the desired URL with the actual URL like this:

```
blogs/{{entry}} => blog/article/{{entry}}
```

Then people will be able to visit `blogs/entry-title` and EE will treat it as if they visited `blog/article/entry-title` and use the appropriate template_group/template.

Comment: As another alternative and as Freeway's younger brother is [Freebie](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freebie) which would also do the job for your use case.

Comment: Thank you Ian. This seem to be a nice Addon that could solve my issue with the URI. Thank you for your suggestion. Have a nice day.

Comment: with this example, what happes to blogs/P12 (pagination)?

Comment: I did not implement this yet as I am new to ExpressionEngine. I just display 8 entries and make a like to a archive to see the rest as per year on title.

Answer (score 3):

In the past i used to have an elaborate `{exp:switchee}` tag in de blog/index template, that would check for various possibilities for segment_2. Process a channel:entries tag accordingly, wether it is a number (archives), or pagination (P12), otherwise treat it like a url_title. (pseudo code)

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_2}" parse="inward"}
{case value="#/d+#"}
  // number means archives
  // process further? e.g. months etc. 2012/04
{/case}
{case value="''|#^P/d+#"}
  //pagination or empty (meaning index)
{/case}
{case default="yes"}
  // not empty, expecting url_title
{/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

Edit: But actually, i went back to more separate templates for detail views (single entry), archives and listviews. Not have one huge index template anymore.

Comment: I prefer using switchee to accomplish this. It's relatively easy to understand and if you comment your templates correctly easy to maintain in the future.

Comment: Thank you GDMac for the solution, however, this seems much complicated than the solution Ian posted above. Thank you for your suggestion and have a nice day.