# How can I remove template name from url?

Tags: ee2

I want to remove template name from URL. I want to display only template_group/entry-name. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove template segment from URL](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9603/remove-template-segment-from-url). Also see [Strict URLs / Removing one template group name](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14018/strict-urls-removing-one-template-group-name)

Comment: Alex - both those questions refer to removing the template group, which is very different to removing the template name. Albeit both can be resolved with similar add-ons, the native solutions would be quite different, so justifies a separate question.

Comment: I misinterpreted the question. Close vote retracted and +1 for your answer @PeterLewis ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Template Routes](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/template-routes) plugin to override the default routing.

You'd add something like this to your index.php:

```
$config['template_routes'] = array(
  'template_group/:any' => 'template_group/template_name'
);
```

and then just do something with the $1 value in the template.

Answer (score 3):

As Robson & Bhashkar have stated, use the index template in the template group to do the channel:entries tag pair - therefore doing away with the template reference in the URL. If you target template_group, it automatically uses the index template without you specifying /template_group/index.

You're trying to utilise the same template (template_group/index) for both the listing and the details - that's absolutely fine, just utilise no_results...

Let's assume template_group is "blog", the URLs you want are:

- /blog (listing)
- /blog/my-article (details - not /blog/details/my-article)

Assume you're accessing the entry details first, so blog/index template:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="blog"
    dynamic="yes"
    require_entry="yes"
    track_views="one"
    disable="member_data|pagination"}
    {if no_results}
        {embed=blog/listing}
    {/if}

... display of blog details page   ...

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This will attempt to pull an entry based on the URL - if it can't match it, it will fall into the no_results conditional and embed the listing page...

Template blog/listing (note this template isn't the URL!)

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="news"
    dynamic="no" 
    orderby="date"
    sort="desc"
    paginate="bottom" paginate_base="/blog"
    limit="10"}

    ...listing details...
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be just put the code within the "index" template of that template group. By doing it, you can have the URL like template_group/entry-name.

Comment: @ Bhashkar sir i am already using "index" template for article list page and for article detail page i am using template_group/template/article-name so now i want to remove details and i want to use template_group/article_name now how this is possible ?